# How to chart tubes around manifolds with boundary/corners?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, manifolds, stratifications

Let $M \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a manifold with boundary/corners. For example, a piece of curve with endpoints or a $2d$ unit square in $\{ z = 0 \}$. I am interested in introducing local coordinates in the $\varepsilon$-tube defined as $\{ x \colon d ( x, M ) < \varepsilon \}$ around $M$. The tubular neighbourhood theorem gives a way to do so in the vicinity of each inner point of $M$, however the points of $\partial M$ are not covered by this construction.

What I've looked at so far: I've seen the notion of a collar of a manifold, but I don't understand how to use it together with the tubular neighbourhood coordinates. I've also heard of tubular neighbourhood theorem for stratified manifolds, but I couldn't find a good reference. Another idea is to take the tubular neighborhood of some smooth extension of $M$, but I haven't seen any results on such extensions.

So, my question is this: what is the "standard" way of introducing local coordinates *on the tubes around* manifolds with boundaries/corners?

---

Here's a picture from Alfred Gray's book "Tubes". I am looking for some way to chart the caps (left side of the picture). Tubular neighbourhood theorem gives me a nice fibre bundle structure for the neighbourhood on the right.

[image]

Here's another picture from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0511502):

[image]

Comment: I guess you are aware of the fact that there is no chance for the tubular neighborhood construction working for manifolds with corners in the classical sense for the situation you describe. THe reason is that your manifold is in the thickening not a "neat" submanifold. The situation is discussed in Michors book manifolds of differentiable mappings (available online here: https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/manifolds_of_differentiable_mappings.pdf). The definition can be found in 2.5 and the tubular neighborhood theorem is then following later in the book.

Comment: A question I have: What do you mean by "what is the "standard" way of introducing local coordinates on manifolds with boundaries"? Your question is asking for the \epsilon thickening of the manifold and this is something extrinsic after you have a given embedding.

Comment: @AlexanderSchmeding, thanks for the reference! Yes, I know that tubular neighbourhood theorem only works for neat submanifolds. I was vague with the use of word "standard", what I mean is: imagine you have a manifold $M$ already embedded into $\mathbb{R}^d$. Then its $\varepsilon$-thickening is well-defined. Then, under some assumptions, there are ways of making this $M_\varepsilon$ into a manifold. If $M$ is neat, then this is done by tubular neighbourhood theorem. Is it possible to do something similar if it's not? For example, a piece of smooth line $\{ x = f(t), \ t \in [0, 1] \}$.

Comment: I think you have something different in mind when writing about the $\varepsilon$ thickening as a manifold. Since this will always be an open subset of euclidean space it has a trivial manifold structure, but arguably that is not the one you are after?

Comment: @AlexanderSchmeding, yes, I want a manifold structure compatible with that of $M$. I want my local coordinates on $M_\varepsilon$ to be the local coordinates in $M$ + the normal coordinates. Near the boundary I want to somehow extend the local coordinates of $M$.

Comment: @AlexanderSchmeding, I've added a picture to the post.

Comment: thanks, that clarifies it a lot

Comment: @AlexanderSchmeding, I had an idea to represent $M = \operatorname{Int} M \cup \partial M$ and then choose some "half-tube" near $\partial M$, but I don't know whether it's possible to make it compatible with the tube around $\operatorname{Int} M$.

Comment: I think the main issue is the corner case you also asked for. In the smooth boundary case I would simply try to go to the double and construct the tube by hand using a Riemannian exponential map of a Riemannian metric on the double for which the boundary is a totally geodesic submanifold. (Such a thing always exists, see e.g. the 1970 annals of math paper by Ebin/Marsden.) Then one should be able to construct coordinates which parametrise the boundary, the interior of the manifold and a strip around it using that the normal direction is orthogonal to the other via the choice of metric.

Comment: however, such a construction does not work for manifolds with corners.

Comment: I wonder if one can start with a tubular neighborhood of the corners, then construct a compatible tubular neighborhood of the edges, then construct a compatible tubular neighborhood of the manifold itself.

Comment: Your question is poorly phrased.  Specifically "what is the "standard" way of introducing local coordinates on manifolds with boundaries?" -- manifolds with corners are defined with standard local coordinates, being diffeomorphisms between open subsets of the manifold with open subsets of $[0, \infty)^n$.   But the details you provide indicate this is not the question you are asking.  You are asking about the structure of regular neighbourhoods of submanifolds.

Comment: @RyanBudney, please tell me what I should clarify for my question to make more sense and I shall gladly do so. I also hope that the pictures I've provided show my aim clearly. Maybe it's not the case. Anyway, differential geometry is not my area and I may lack some basics. But yes, you are right, I am asking about the neighbourhood, I know the definitions related to manifolds with corners.

Comment: The question you want to ask is, "if I have a manifold with corners embedded in another manifold (maybe with corners), generally not properly embedded, is there a description of its regular neighbourhood analogous to the tubular neighbourhood theorem?"  Your pictures indicate a stratified version of the tubular neighbourhood theorem, but perhaps it should just be described as a "regular neighbourhood theorem".

Comment: @RyanBudney, this is exactly what I'd like to know, yes.

Answer (score 3):

From the comments I think the theorem you are looking for is this.  I'll be a little fast and loose just to make it easier to state.

Let $M$ be a manifold with corners and $N$ a submanifold, potentially not properly embedded.  So $[0,1]^2$ as a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ would qualify, for example, and similarly $[0,1]^2 \times \mathbb R$ as a subset of $\mathbb R^3$ or $[0,1] \times \mathbb R^2$.  I suppose this should be called something like semi-properly embedded.  We do demand that each connected stratum of $N$ is mapped to just one connected stratum of $M$, as in the above listed examples.

Then there exists an essentially unique regular neighbourhood of $N$ in $M$ and it has a description similar to a stratified space, all definable in terms of the normal bundle of $N$ in $M$, and the stratifications of $M$ and $N$ respectively.

The `top' stratum is the normal bundle of $N$ in $M$.

The co-dimension $1$ stratum consists of the restriction of the normal bundle to $M$ in $N$ to  $\partial_1 M \setminus \partial_1 N$, but then you have to take a direct sum with $[0,\infty)$.   Here $\partial_1 M$ means the co-dimension one boundary stratum of $M$.  Similarly $\partial_2 M$ means the co-dimension two strata, i.e. the traditional `corners', for example $\partial_2 [0,\infty)^2 = \{(0,0)\}$.

The co-dimension 2 stratum of the regular neighbourhood consists of the normal bundle to $M$ in $N$ restricted to $\partial_2 M$, but then you have to take a direct sum with $[0,\infty)^k$ depending on which stratum of $M$ you are in. $k=2$ for the interior stratum, $k=1$ for the co-dimension one stratum and $k=0$ for the co-dimension two stratum.

etc.

These spaces you glue together in the natural way, and you have a corresponding embedding from this total space to the ambient manifold $M$.

I could revise this to be more precise but let me know if that makes sense.  It corresponds to your images, but my response deals with some cases you did not include in your images.

Comment: This is actually very promising! Do you have a reference for this construction? Somewhere where it's fully described (along with some existence theorem)?

Comment: If you do a little searching you'll find several references for manifolds with cubical corners on this forum.  I am not certain if anyone has written down a regular neighbourhood theorem in this level of detail.  But the above is the theorem.  It's proof would basically be the same as the proof of the tubular neighbourhood theorem, but you'd have to adapt to manifolds with cubical corners. Unfortunately manifolds with cubical corners is one of those topics that  gets covered without much fanfare, fairly quietly in non-obvious papers.

Comment: Here are a few threads: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/387304/collar-neighborhood-theorem-for-manifold-with-corners  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/199021/manifold-with-corners  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103785/a-category-of-manifolds-that-includes-polygonal-domains  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452553/morse-theory-for-manifolds-with-boundary

Comment: They might have the reference you need.  If you don't find it there, you might need to write up the proof yourself.